# Не выводит List в консоль

Tags: c++, list, stl, вывод, случайные-числа

Код программы:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "list"
#include "iterator"

using namespace std;

void show (list <int> l) {
    int i=-1;
    list<int>::iterator it;
    for (it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); ++it) {
        i++;
        if (i % 4 == 0)cout << endl;
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
}

void make_l (list <int> l,int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        l.push_back(rand()%100+0);
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    list<int> listok;
    int n;
    cout << "Введите количество переменных в лист: ";
    cin >> n;
    make_l(listok, n);
    show(listok);
    cout << "Отсортированный лист: \n";
    listok.sort();
    show(listok);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите не это

```
void make_l (list <int> l,int n) {
```

Вы передаете по значению, то есть, функция получает **копию**, и по выходу с функции все теряется. Конечно, потом в таком списке ничего не будет. Делайте так

```
void make_l (list <int>& l,int n) {
```

и заодно поправил бы

```
if (i % 4 == 0)cout << endl;
```

на

```
if (i % 4 == 1)cout << endl;
```

что бы вывод был красивее.

Comment: спасибо) с ссылкой на list что-то у меня не получается, я просто void переделал в list и вернул его, теперь все заработало! спасибо, я понял принцип. list<int> make_l (list <int> listok,int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        listok.push_back(rand()%100+0);
    }
    return listok;
}

Comment: не получилось, потому что я чуточку не там поставил амперсанд. Уже исправил. А в Вашем варианте теперь можно параметр не передавать. Нет смысла. просто объявите переменную типа список прям в функции.